# Is there a way to get an alert if pm2 auto restarts a process because of max memory usage?

Tags: pm2

I would like to setup an alert in my monitoring system to keep track of memory based restarts.  I'm using the flags here https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/features/memory-limit/

```
     "max_memory_restart": '3296M',
```

Ideally i would like to be able to call a shell script or run a node program before the auto restart happens.